# Different behavior of index(after:) in Collection and String

Tags: swift

I'm curious, why this code works without any kind of error:

```
let a = [1]
print(a.index(after: a.endIndex)) // 2
```

But if we try to repeat this code with `String` type, we get an error:

```
let s = "a"
print(s.index(after: s.endIndex)) // Fatal error: Can't advance past endIndex
```

According to [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2943746-index) and [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1782583-index) docs, they all have same statement:

> A valid index of the collection. `i` must be less than `endIndex`.

Is it a bug or all works as it should? I'm using swift 4.2.

Comment: Does seem buggy (certainly goes against what the docs say).

Comment: `Array` has its own implementations of various things. You're still going to blow up if you try to use the index.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes but the Array declaration is still commented with the phrase "`i` must be less than `endIndex`” right there in the standard library header.

Comment: Fair enough, @matt

Comment: This has been discussed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/behaviour-of-collection-index-limitedby/19083. In particular (for Array): *"NOTE: Range checks are not performed here, because it is done later by the subscript function."*

Comment: @MartinR, already found this in source code. thanks for the link!

Comment: @MartinR But can we agree that the docs are a bug?

Comment: @matt: I would tend to consider the *implementation* a bug, and that it should trap in -Onone and -O builds – that is also how I understand Ben Cohen's answer in the above mentioned forum thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go to the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L509) of `Array`, we can find:

```
public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
    // NOTE: this is a manual specialization of index movement for a Strideable
    // index that is required for Array performance.  The optimizer is not
    // capable of creating partial specializations yet.
    // NOTE: Range checks are not performed here, because it is done later by
    // the subscript function.
    return i + 1
}
```

In this case, we can rewrite code like this and finally get the crash:

```
let a = [1]
let index = a.index(after: a.endIndex)
print(a[index])
```

So, all works "as expected" for `Array` type, but we **must** check the result `index` by yourself, if we don't want to get crash at runtime

P.S. Useful link by @[MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r): https://forums.swift.org/t/behaviour-of-collection-index-limitedby/19083/3

Comment: I guess I should have posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, yeah, you definitely should! but i did some research and post answer by myself. sorry about that.

Comment: No, no need to apologize! You _should_ answer your own question if you have a good solution.